# Paypal recurring billing with a trial and discount code

Tags: paypal, recurring, trial, discount

I have a membership website where membership costs $19.99/month. I'd like to give my users 2 weeks trial period AND a discunt for the first month of payment after that. That is:

- User purchases a membership which costs $19.99/month
- I give the user 2 weeks free trial and after that 2 weeks I charge the user $9.99 and every other payment after that should be $19.99.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: Not really sure why this was downvoted. Paypal documentation is extremely poor on the subject ( at least it was when writing the question ) and using SO community seemed like a logical choice ( proven right choice by having a correct answer )

Comment: @Matthew Well they still dont have any thing for discount/coupons on recurring billing/agreements. Atleast I couldnt find it in their docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the start date of the profile to 2 weeks from the current date.  Then set the trial amount to 9.99 and have it run for 1 month, and then set the regular amount to 19.99/mo.

This will create an active profile immediately, but nothing will be charged at all until the start date that was set.  At that point it'll charge whatever you set for the trial amount, and then it would charge the regular amount after that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually did go in that direction but I wasn't sure if the initial amount would be charged right away or after the free trial. Thanx man!